# Excel macro to loop through range until value found, populate range below found cell with formula

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a large table, sometimes with hundreds of rows.
This table is generated by another application that exports to excel.

One column has the heading "Adjusted Price".
I want all the rows in this column to contain a formula (presently they're all 0's).

I want to automate this process because the table gets regenerated all the time.

This column may not always be in the same place. **So I need a macro that can find this column ("Adjusted Price") and then fill all the cells in that column with a formula (with the exception of the first row of course).**

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes this can be done. People requesting help with code are **expected** to show original effort. Get started on a [mcve] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homework is to figure out how to plug it in!

```
Option Explicit

Sub setAdjustedPrice()

    Dim column As Integer
    Dim adjustedPriceColumn As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim rowCount As Long

    column = 1
    rowCount = 1

    Do While Range(FncAlphaCon(column) & rowCount).Value <> "" And found = False

        If (Range(FncAlphaCon(column) & rowCount).Value = "Adjusted Price") Then

            found = True
            adjustedPriceColumn = FncAlphaCon(column)

        Else

            column = column + 1

        End If

    Loop

    If found = True Then

        Do While rowCount < ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            Range(adjustedPriceColumn & rowCount) = "YOUR FORMULA"

        Loop

    Else

        MsgBox ("'Adjusted Price' column not found, cannot continue.")

    End If

End Sub

Private Function FncAlphaCon(aNumber As Integer) As String
' Fixed version 27/10/2011

    Dim letterArray As String
    Dim iterations As Integer

    letterArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

        If aNumber <= 26 Then

            FncAlphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, aNumber, 1))

        Else

            If aNumber Mod 26 = 0 Then

                iterations = Int(aNumber / 26)
                FncAlphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, iterations - 1, 1)) & (Mid$(letterArray, 26, 1))

            Else

                'we deliberately round down using 'Int' as anything with decimal places is not a full iteration.
                iterations = Int(aNumber / 26)
                FncAlphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, iterations, 1)) & (Mid$(letterArray, (aNumber - (26 * iterations)), 1))

            End If

        End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it and it works perfectly. Good job!